# App doesn't enter in the initial ViewController using Typhoon

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have created a project to test the Typhoon framework , I have created two classes `ApplicationAssembly` and `CoreAssembly` where I inject some properties and constructors and a default `Configuration.plist` to load data from it.

> **ApplicationAssembly**

```
public class ApplicationAssembly: TyphoonAssembly { 

    public dynamic func config() -> AnyObject {
       return TyphoonDefinition.configDefinitionWithName("Config.plist")
    } 
}
```

> **CoreAssembly**

```
public class CoreAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

    public dynamic func apiHandler() -> AnyObject {
       return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(ApiHandler.self) {
           (definition) in

           definition.useInitializer("initWithDebugging:debugProcess:mainURL:") {
              (initializer) in

               initializer.injectParameterWith(TyphoonConfig("debug_mode"))
               initializer.injectParameterWith(TyphoonConfig("debug_path"))
               initializer.injectParameterWith(TyphoonConfig("api_url"))                
           }
           definition.scope = TyphoonScope.Singleton
       }
    }    

    public dynamic func viewController() -> AnyObject {

       return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(ViewController.self) {
           (definition) in

           definition.injectProperty("apiHandler", with:self.apiHandler())
       }
    }   
}
```

I set in my `Info.plist` the `TyphoonInitialAssemblies` first the `ApplicationAssembly` and then the `CoreAssembly`.

Everything works fine without exceptions or anything except that the app never enters in `AppDelegate` neither in the `ViewController` class. I don't know maybe I missed something in the doc or anything.

What I'm missing here?

Why in debug not enter in the `ViewController` class that is the  initial view controller in Storyboard?

Comment: Let's see if its Typhoon related first. Does the app launch correctly when there's no TyphoonInitialAssemblies in the Info.plist?

Comment: @JasperBlues Yes it's the problem if I remove the TyphoonInitialAssemblies in the Info.plist all run fine

Comment: I'm not sure what to look at next. Possible to send a sample project via Typhoon's Github?

Comment: Yes of course, let me make a repo and send you the link.

Comment: @JasperBlues Please make fork in the [project](https://github.com/Vkt0r/TyphoonTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the ApiHandler class does not extend NSObject, which is a requirement. This is because Typhoon is an introspective Dependency Injection container. As Swift has no native introspection it uses the Objective-C run-time.

The App should not however have crashed in such an obfuscated way. I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/341) to look at how to fail with a meaningful error, rather than infinitely recurse.

After solving the initial problem, I also noted that the init method for ApiHandler passing in a Swift Bool object. This needs to be an NSNumber.

```
init(debugging : NSNumber, debugProcess : String, mainURL : String) {
    self.debugging = debugging.boolValue
    self.debugProcess = debugProcess
    self.mainURL = mainURL                
}
```

Given that Typhoon uses the Objective-C runtime, there are a few quirks to using it with Swift - the same kinds of rules outlined for using Swift with KVO apply.